# SQL Server View with many OR statements with very specific Account lookups is that a problem?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been working on a view in SQL Server which another developer added, which has a lot of `OR` statements with specific accounts -  I am feeling like

1. this is bad practice, what is better?  Another view to join?
2. requires a lot more testing to be sure to get the results
3. seems like the View now is possibly slower? Performance on doing this?
4. What an eye soar for a generic view,  maintaining that and getting it rolled to production for every time an account is added (seems like some holding table would be ideal)

Here is the `WHERE` clause with all these new OR statements:

```
WHERE   
    Source = 'DST' 
    AND bs.Name <> 'Closed'
    AND dst.BreakId IS NOT NULL
    AND ((dst.Account = 79350523 AND dst.ReconRecord IS NULL) --for DST suspense
         OR (dst.Account IN (98620036,98620664)) --for MFR suspense since we will need to include divnet (reconrecord is not null) in calculation
         OR (dst.Account IN (3157-6218, 7848-4182, 7935-0411, 7935-8987, 8460-8721)) -- For PPS Suspense
         OR (dst.Account IN (79340000, 79350304, 79350410, 79350700, 79358505, 79351733, 79352084))) -- For SPS Suspense
```

What would be an example of a better way to do this with another View to join OR perhaps to some table(s) to join in for "PPS" "SPS" etc.. ?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this other programmer tested the logic completely. For example, one of the values is **3157-6218**. That is a mathematical expression. If that is supposed to represent a range, it won't work. If it represents an actual account number, then why is all the code using numeric literals (and it still won't work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add properties (MFR, PPS, SPS) in account table for each purpose?  So you don't have to update your view each times.

And update the where clause like :

```
WHERE   Source = 'DST' AND bs.Name <> 'Closed'
    AND   dst.BreakId IS NOT NULL
    AND   (account.MFR = 1 OR account.PPS = 1 OR account.SPS = 1)
```